How to prevent Pelican from copying Markdown source files into output folder?
I am converting my Jekyll blog to Pelican. The directory structure of the source content folder uses YYYY/MM/DD/slug.md to organize blog posts and stores static files in files/YYYY/filename.ext. Static pages are in pages/filename.md:
content
|-- 2023
|   |-- 01
|   |   |-- 01
|   |   |   |-- plans-for-the-year.md
|   |   |   +-- sdxjs-introduction.md
|   |   |-- 02
|   |   |   +-- sdxjs-systems-programming.md
|   |   |-- 03
|   |   |   +-- sdxjs-async-programming.md
|   |   |-- 04
|   |   |   +-- sdxjs-unit-test.md
|-- 2024
|   |-- 01
|   |   |-- 03
|   |   |   +-- the-other-examples.md
|-- files
|   |-- 2023
|   |   |-- awesome-robot.png
|   |   |-- blackberry-pie.jpg
+-- pages
    +-- about.md

I have added the following to my pelicanconf.py settings file:
OUTPUT_SOURCES = False

SLUGIFY_SOURCE = "basename"
ARTICLE_URL = "{date:%Y}/{date:%m}/{date:%d}/{slug}/"
ARTICLE_SAVE_AS = "{date:%Y}/{date:%m}/{date:%d}/{slug}/index.html"
PAGE_URL = "{slug}/"
PAGE_SAVE_AS = "{slug}/index.html"

The HTML files are generated as I want and where I want, but the source Markdown files are copied to the output directory as well, despite explicitly setting OUTPUT_SOURCES to False as suggested in the docs. I could add another line to Makefile to delete these unwanted files after the build, but how can I prevent them being copied in the first place?

Pelican: 4.10.0
Python: 3.12.6


Try as I might, I cannot reproduce the behavior you described. Have you followed all the steps in the How to Get Help documentation? Also, have you considered putting your content source in a publicly-accessible place (e.g., GitHub) to facilitate review and potential suggestions?

I have created a repository https://github.com/gvwilson/pelican-demo that holds a subset of the files I'm converting. To replicate, git clone, create a virtual environment and activate it, pip install "pelican[markdown]", then make html and find docs -name '*.md'.

It took quite a while to track down the source of the problem. I started by removing all the content except a single article. Generating that yielded no problems, making it pretty clear the issue was caused by the content and not Pelican, settings, theme, etc. Selectively moving over more content, folder by folder, eventually yielded one of the problematic Markdown files. Then I removed and re-added content in that file, bit by bit, until I found the troublesome line. While time-consuming, you might consider this technique when troubleshooting in the future. (^_^)

For the other issues you mentioned in your test repository's README, I suggest submitting them as separate topics under Pelican Discussions, where more folks may see your queries than here on S.O.

Hi Greg. Did my answer resolve your problem? If so, would you please accept it?

The source of this problem appears to originate from two Markdown files in your content:

content/2023/01/01/sdxjs-introduction.md
content/2024/04/01/sdxjs-introduction.md

In both files, there is the following reference link near the bottom:
[third_bit]: {static}/

Changing the link target to / (which is what I imagine was the original intention) fixes the problem:
[third_bit]: /

